# Wordpress Custom search page other than search.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to include custom Hashtag search page in my Wordpress theme.And I have the following code in functions.php file

```
function hashtag_template( $template ){
  global $wp_query;
  $hash = get_query_var('hashtag');
  if( !empty($hash) ){
    return locate_template('hashtags-search.php');
  }
  return $template;
}
add_action( 'template_include', 'hashtag_template' );
```

and I have also added a `hashtag-search.php` template

but when I am searching with `www.mysite.com/?hashtag=string`, it does not shows that(hashtag-search.php) search page.Where may be the problem?

Comment: You might need to register your query var first: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/#custom-query-vars. Also, you could technically use the default `search.php` and then check for the url parameter and do a `get_template_part()` if that parameter exists.

Comment: @disinfor yes now working but not in a separate page like search, its showing in homepage